# Drawing best practice and datum self-referencing

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm in a bit of a pickle with one of the quality techns that works for us (the company) over a profile of surface tolerance. I initially submitted something resembling figure 1 (top capture) and quality came back to me saying figure 2 (bottom capture) would be better.

I've never seen ''auto-referencing'' of datum and I don't see the point because it doesn't add anything to the GD&T. I've never seen anything like this in any book, reference or drawing I stumbled upon over my (short) carreer. Are there any arguments to which practice would be best? I'm open to any source saying one way should be the preferred one.

Thanks!

[image: What I'm proposing]

[image: What quality guy suggests]

Comment: Be a heckuva lot easier if you circled the differences.

Comment: Where are Datums B and C?

Comment: Differences are now circled in red, datums B and C are the 2 0.2 holes.

Comment: I see. You can't reference a feature back to itself. Your first version is more appropriate, but not ideal. How do you plan to inspect the position of the first hole(datum b)? I see what you're trying to accomplish. I think you need to remove the tolerance of position for that hole and give datum C twice the tolerance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it. It's probably not legal in any GD&T spec.

You can't reference a feature back to itself(think: chicken or egg?).

Your first version is more appropriate, but not ideal. How do you plan to inspect the position of the first hole(datum b)? I see what you're trying to accomplish(intent), but it should be clear from an inspection stand point. I think you need to remove the tolerance of position for that datum B hole and give datum C twice the tolerance...

Btw, do your holes sizes have a tolerance or fall back on a general note?

Comment: You're right for the tolerance of position on the hole on datum B and giving twice the tolerance for datum C. In the original drawing, datum B had no tolerance of position. The 0.2 is toleranced via the title block of the drawing. For obvious IP reasons, I recreated a quick mock-up of the drawing to illustrate the problem and I oversaw some details.

Comment: @HotFuzz I figured as much. I just want to cover all the bases.